# Incorrect "Invalid Arguments" errors given by Eclipse code analyzer

Tags: c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, codan

I am using cocos2d-x library and trying to call couple of functions from it. The code compiles without any error while the code analyzer keeps complaining about "Invalid Arguments" in two functions:

```
static inline ccColor3B ccc3(const GLubyte r, const GLubyte g, const GLubyte b);
static CCTintTo* create(float duration, GLubyte red, GLubyte green, GLubyte blue);
```

All other calls work perfectly. The common thing between these two that is not available in the other functions is the usage of GLubyte. GLubyte is defined as follows:

```
typedef unsigned char GLubyte;
```

I don't believe that the problem lies in the way I call the methods, but here is a snippet about the related parts:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
USING_NS_CC;
...
ccColor3B color=ccc3(250,200,100);
```

It looks like that the problem is caused by CODAN. So my question is: What should I change/add in my code in order to satisfy the analyzer and remove all these errors? I would prefer not disabling it, so any manual solution would suffice.